# Having issue with my automod system in disocrd.py

Tags: discord.py

So, I'm trying to make an event that if anyone send any invite link, my BOT will detect, delete it and mute the user as well as send a log in my log channel tell that a user try to send an invite link in the server
This is my code so far:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(ctx, message):
    discordInviteFilter = re.compile("(...)?(?:https?://)?discord(?:(?:app)?\.com/invite|\.gg)/?[a-zA-Z0-9]+/?")
    guild = ctx.guild
    embed1=discord.Embed(title="Muted successfully", colour=red)
    embed1.set_thumbnail(url=message.member.avatar_url)
    embed1.add_field(name="Reason", value=f"Send invite link", inline=False)
    mutedRole = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=" | Muted")
    channel = discord.utils.get(message.member.guild.channels, name="║logs")
    if discordInviteFilter.match(message.content):
        await ctx.message.delete()
        await ctx.message.channel.send(f'{ctx.message.author.mention}, invite link are not allowed here. Please read the rules again')
    await bot.process_commands(message)
    await ctx.message.author.add_roles(mutedRole)    
    await channel.send(embed=embed1)
```

And when I run my code and send an invite link, this is the error I have

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Blue\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: on_message() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message'
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Blue\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: on_message() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message'
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Blue\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: on_message() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message'
```

Is there any mistake these lines? I need your help. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are giving 2 arguments to `on_message` event, which takes only one argument i.e., `message`.

Remove `ctx` argument and try this code:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    discordInviteFilter = re.compile("(...)?(?:https?://)?discord(?:(?:app)?\.com/invite|\.gg)/?[a-zA-Z0-9]+/?")
    guild = message.guild
    embed1=discord.Embed(title="Muted successfully")
    embed1.set_thumbnail(url=message.author.avatar_url)
    embed1.add_field(name="Reason", value=f"Send invite link", inline=False)
    mutedRole = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=" | Muted")
    channel = discord.utils.get(message.author.guild.channels, name="║logs")
    if discordInviteFilter.match(message.content):
        await message.delete()
        await message.channel.send(f'{message.author.mention}, invite link are not allowed here. Please read the rules again')
        await bot.process_commands(message)
        await message.author.add_roles(mutedRole)    
        await channel.send(embed=embed1)
```

Comment: Oh, so the on_message can only be used for 1 argument. I'll take note that

Comment: Btw, I can use message. for something like message.author the same way as ctx.author, right?

Comment: Yes, you can do that

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you have the argument `ctx` which should not be included. `on_message` should have one argument, `message`.

Try something like this:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message: discord.Message):
    discordInviteFilter = re.compile("(...)?(?:https?://)?discord(?:(?:app)?\.com/invite|\.gg)/?[a-zA-Z0-9]+/?")
    guild = message.guild
    embed1=discord.Embed(title="Muted successfully", colour=red)
    embed1.set_thumbnail(url=message.member.avatar_url)
    embed1.add_field(name="Reason", value=f"Send invite link", inline=False)
    mutedRole = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=" | Muted")
    channel = discord.utils.get(message.member.guild.channels, name="║logs")
    if discordInviteFilter.match(message.content):
        await message.delete()
        await message.channel.send(f'{message.author.mention}, invite links are not allowed here. Please read the rules again')
    await bot.process_commands(message)
    await message.author.add_roles(mutedRole)    
    await channel.send(embed=embed1)
```

[Reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_message#discord.on_message)

I would also recommend moving your discord invite filter regex compilation to only happen once (outside the function) and move as much of the code as possible to be within the if statement so you don't have to run it unless needed.